# Java Mail client not working on Linux

Tags: java, linux, email, zimbra

I have an email ssl client for zimbra mail server that work perfectly on windows but i got a failure authentication on linux, i had verified that all that network conf. dns, port and firewall are correct

the properties for session:

```
props.put("mail.smtps.host", "my.mail.server");
props.put("mail.smtps.host", "my.mail.server");
props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtps.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.trust", "my.mail.server");
```

Getting the session:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
```

Transport :

```
Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
t.connect("user", "pass");
t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

something that got my attention when using debug, is the postfix response in the message

**Windows Debug Log:**

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3 DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP:
>   trying to connect to host "my.mail.server", port 465, isSSL true 220
>   my.mail.server **ESMTP ready**. DEBUG SMTP: connected to host
>   "my.mail.server", port: 465

**meanwhile on Linux i got this:**

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3 DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP:
>   trying to connect to host "my.mail.server", port 465, isSSL true 220
>   my.mail.server **ESMTP Postfix** DEBUG SMTP: connected to host
>   "my.mail.server", port: 465

i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, the server auth was different for local and external access, for development we were using a windows server outside the net, and linux server for intranet.

In fact, it was a misconfiguration on mail server

The java mail client remains the same now for local and public access.

Comment: I could not provide an answer with the specific same configuration, because this thread is about the mail client. I have answered just to provide enough information to a developer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in debug messages is not significant.  It is just a cosmetic difference in what the two (local) mail servers put in their "connection greeting reply" line.  For example, a Linux server that is running [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) as its [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) will typically say:

```
220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix
```

The [ESMTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) says:

> *"SMTP server implementations MAY include identification of their
>      software and version information in the connection greeting reply
>      after the 220 code, a practice that permits more efficient isolation
>      and repair of any problems.  Implementations MAY make provision for
>      SMTP servers to disable the software and version announcement where
>      it causes security concerns."*

The real problem will be something else.

If I was trying to debug this, I would start by looking at the MTA logs to see if they say why the session is being shut down.  I would also check that the user / password are correct and that the MTA has been configured appropriately to allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: I had made some research, zimbra uses a postfix mta, but i do not understand how the same smtp client works on windows. Maybe a misconfiguraton on linux server could affect ?

Comment: Possibly.  But that is speculation.  Look at the log files.